# Find the maximum value in vector<vector<int>> without a 'for' loop

Tags: c++

We know that for `vector<int> A`, we can use `*max_element(A.begin(), A.end())` to find the maximum value in `A`. However, I would like to know whether there is clean way to find the maximum value in a `vector<vector<int>> B`, avoiding using `for` loop?

If we use a `for` loop, the code could be trivial like:

```
int maxvalue = INT_MIN;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        maxvalue = max(maxvalue, B[i][j]);
```

or

```
int maxvalue = INT_MIN;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    int temp = *max_element(B[i].begin(), B[i].end());
    maxvalue = max(maxvalue, temp);
}
```

But I still feel it not clean enough. And I don't like the `for` loop.

---

Finally, I chose the following code to do it:

```
auto itv = max_element(A.begin(), A.end(), [](vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b)
        { return *max_element(a.begin(), a.end()) < *max_element(b.begin(), b.end()); });
int ans = *max_element(itv->begin(), itv->end());
```

Comment: For loops are great. Combine them with iterators and you are gold.

Comment: @c-wang: Have you tried using a custom comparator function which compares between `*max_element()` of two `vector<int>`s ?

Comment: No, how? Please give me some hint of the code.

Comment: @c-wang: I haven't tested it. I am not even sure if something like that would work. Just a passing thought.

Comment: Loops are fine. I wouldn't worry about using a more complicated method.

Comment: @c-wang: Custom comparators *do* get the job done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a custom comparison operator in `max_element()` to get the desired effect. No loops whatsoever, except the implied accumulation that `max_element()` runs.

```
bool mycomp(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
  return *max_element(a.begin(), a.end()) < *max_element(b.begin(), b.end());
}

vector<vector<int>> vv; // our vector of vectors

auto itv = max_element(vv.begin(), vv.end(), mycomp); // find the vector 
                                                     // with the max element

int answer = *max_element((*itv).begin(), (*itv).end()); // finds the max element 
                                                        // in the desired vector
```

This is by no means *clean*. But it does what it says it does.

Comment: is it possible to use lambda function to replace `mycomp`?

Comment: With reference to the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228231/find-the-max-value-in-vectorvectorint-without-for-loop/36228587#comment60087842_36228231

Comment: @c-wang: I see no reason why not.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. It is worthy to note that @crazy-eddie code does the same thing, essentially (in perhaps a more efficient way).

Comment: This version makes WAY more comparisons than mine.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Indeed, it does. Mine is very inefficient for large datasets.

Answer (score 5):

```
auto max_value = std::accumulate(std::begin(B), std::end(B),
      std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), 
      [] (int cur_max, auto && vec) 
      { 
        return std::max(cur_max, *std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `for` loop you could use `std::for_each`. Maybe something like:

```
int maxvalue = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
std::for_each(std::begin(B), std::end(B), [&maxvalue](const auto& v)
{
    maxvalue = std::max(maxvalue, *std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(b)));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the thing you want to avoid using loops are long structures in your program, using **C++11** you can find the maximum in a single line **with loops**:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > w;


int max = 0;
for (auto i : w) for (auto j : i) max = j > max ? j : max;
```

Or

```
int max = 0;
for (auto i : w) for (auto j : i) if (j > max) max = j;
```

Anyway, I don't think this is a good practice. This option would be better:

```
int max = 0;
for (auto i : w)
    for (auto j : i)
        max = j > max ? j : max;
```

Comment: "without for loop"

Comment: True, it was just something to make it cleaner, I will update the answer

Comment: Worth nothing that putting things in a single line was possible even prior to C++11.

Comment: The point is using those smaller for loops. Of  course you can even write all your c++ code in one single line.